# multiple listener event on javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I added an event for when there is a change in my data-value of a div and when some value is typed in my input
but for some reason it's not arriving at my console.log inside the event

```js
(function initalize() {
  let seleteced = document.querySelector(
    "div.select-box > div.selected"
  );
  console.log(seleteced.dataset.value)
  setTimeout(function() {
    seleteced.dataset.value = 2
    console.log(seleteced.dataset.value)
  }, 3000);
  [
    document.querySelector("div.select-box > div.selected"),
    document.querySelector("div.input_func > div.material-textfield input"),
  ].forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
      console.log("changed");
    });
  });

})();
```

```html
<div class="custom_select flex">
  <h3 class="textfield_label">
    Selecione a categoria da sua Empresa
  </h3>
  <div class="select-box">
    <div class="options-container"></div>
    <div class="selected">
      Selecione um Tipo de Serviço
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input_func">
  <h3 class="textfield_label">
    Quantos Funcionarios têm sua empresa ?
  </h3>
  <div class="material-textfield">
    <input placeholder=" " type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing a data value doesn't trigger the `change` event. This event is only triggered on input elements when the user changes the value.

Comment: change inner.html call on change event?

Comment: No. As I said, the `change` event is only triggered when the value of a user input is changed.

Comment: And it has to be changed by the user, it isn't triggered if you assign to `.value` in JS.